# Weird output when running a simple C++ code in Netbeans

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, cygwin

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int number;
   cout << "Give a number: ";
   cin >> number;

   return 0;
}
```

The code compiles just fine and runs in external terminal as it should. The weird part is the output of Netbeans output window after the run.

When I start running the program and give the number it asks immediately the output is:

```
Process is started in an external terminal ...

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
```

But when I start running the program and **wait** for a moment before giving the number, the Netbeans output window's output turns into this:

```
Process is started in an external terminal ...

RUN FAILED (exit value -1, total time: 5s)
```

This doesn't affect the run in the external terminal since the program runs to the end normally when I give the number. But Netbeans output window still keeps claiming that the run failed which it obviously didn't.

**Is this a known Netbeans bug or is there a way to fix it?**

OS: Windows 7 (64 bit)

Netbeans 7.3.1 with the latest Cygwin tool collection for 64-bit versions of Windows

Comment: I always use Netbeans for C++ developement (Windows 7 x64 through MinGW (GCC 4.7.2) and Manjaro Linux x64 (GCC 4.8.1)) and I never have had any problem. Sounds like a problem with your instalation